# Reference error: guild is not defined. Discord.js bot role kick command error

Tags: discord.js

I'm working on a command for my discord bot to kick everyone in a certain role.
I think what i have should work but i keep on getting a reference error saying guild is not defined

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('-rolekick')) {
          console.log('rolekick')
        guild.members.forEach(member => {
             if (member.roles.has("OutLaw")){
             member.kick()
        }
    })
}
});
```

Comment: You can add a log error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the error says, you haven't defined the variable `guild` anywhere within your code. To get the guild the message was sent in, use [`Message.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild).

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('-rolekick') && message.guild) {
    console.log('rolekick');

    message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
      if (member.roles.find(role => role.name === 'OutLaw')) member.kick()
        .catch(console.error);
    });
  }
});
```